# Starting Apache service with a variable that can be later accessed via PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I have a need to start the Apache service with a parameter so that I can later access that parameter via PHP. Is this possible?

Comment: @Tower, can you please define 'later'? *later* in the page or *later* after several pages?

Comment: I want to supply some data for Apache service, and then access it from PHP. I want this data to be only in memory, not in the filesystem or elsewhere. So, htaccess files or httpd.conf with SetEnv is not an option here. It has to stay on memory, and die along with the service. I just want to access the data via PHP like echo $_SERVER[...]; or something?

Comment: Can we ask what the use case is here? Seems like an odd request.

Comment: I'd like to set a key into the memory that I will use to encrypt data. I don't want this key to exist in the filesystem or in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the parameter to httpd with the `-C` or `-c` (*process the configuration directive before/after reading config files*) [command line option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html#options) and the [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive:

```
httpd -C "SetEnv FOO bar"
```

`FOO` can now be accessed from PHP like so:

```
<?php
print getenv('FOO');
```

prints

```
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an environment variable. See also: [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments on your question, I'd say that using shared memory is an acceptable alternative. Take a look at `shmop_open()` et alia.

Answer (score 0):

the httpd program will take a 'directive' when you start it up using -c, so experiment with that and SetEnv.